# Is the infant mortality rate among African-American babies in Youngstown, Ohio greater than that of babies in Iran?

Tags: united-states, mortality, race, iran

In [a town hall meeting on June 2, 2019](http://www.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1906/02/se.02.html) with Representative Tim Ryan (D-OH), the candidate stated the following (emphasis mine)

> Now, a lot of people don't know, but Youngstown, Ohio is 50 percent African American. I've been working on these issues a long time. We need to address when it comes to African American women what's happening with their health 300 to 400 times - 300 to 400 times higher percentage of death and pregnancy or child birth. Even along education and wealth, income levels, that's an issue we need to address. **An African American baby born in Youngstown, Ohio has a higher infant mortality rate than a baby born in Iran.** I am deeply committed to these issues around justice when it comes to the African American community, and you can bet that I will surround myself with men and women in my administration that will help us put and excellent plan together to make that happen. Thank you.

So is his claim correct? Does an African-American baby born in Youngstown, Ohio have a higher infant mortality rate than a baby (not of a specific ethnicity) born in Iran?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Highly likely. The infant mortality rate in [Iran](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SPDYNIMRTINIRN) is 13 (per 1000 births); the infant mortality rate for African Americans in [Ohio](https://www.cleveland.com/healthfit/2018/12/ohio-infant-deaths-in-2017-second-lowest-on-record-disparity-rises.html) (but not specialized to Youngstown) is 15.6.

There may be difference in [definition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23201/does-the-us-rank-worse-than-other-developed-countries-in-infant-mortality-mostly) (in the USA, some neonatal deaths that are included in the IMR are classified as stillbirths in other countries and excluded), but Ohio would not be the only state where black mothers have Third World levels of infant and maternal mortality.

Comment: ... though this is a difference of 12%, or 1.12 times. That's clearly not the same as the ***300 to 400 times*** (equivalently, 30000%-40000%) difference quoted in the claim. Nor is it even close to a 300%-400% difference, which I suppose is what Tim Ryan probably meant to say. So while your source supports the simple claim that the AA infant mortality rate is *higher*, it suggests that the specific numbers given - even if we charitably assume that Ryan really meant to describe a difference a factor of 100 less than what he literally said - are wildly false.

Comment: That number is in relation to maternal mortality, which does appear to average about 3:1 nationally. https://www.cdc.gov/vitalsigns/maternal-deaths/index.html

Comment: Do you have a source for at least one state "where black mothers have Third World levels of infant and maternal mortality"? Otherwise I don't think it should be part of the answer.

Comment: Iran is not a third world country, so infant mortality rates higher than those in Iran are not necessarily third-world rates.

Comment: @MarkAmery The rate of 15.6 is 20% more than the rate of 13 in Iran, not 12%. And the quote does not state in reference to what other rate this rate of 15.6 is 300% to 400% higher. Perhaps the US average, which was 5.8 in 2017? That's about 2.68 times higher, which is at least in the right ballpark.

Comment: Infant and maternal mortality rates vary wildly across "Third World" countries, so the expression "Third World levels of infant and maternal mortality" really makes very little sense

Comment: @MikeScott: Ireland is a 3rd world country and has an infant mortality rate of 3.60 compared with 5.80 for the USA (Iran has 15.90) (from https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2091rank.html). The 3rd world refers to non aligned nations.

Comment: @Servaes, the 300% comparison is to white residents of Ohio IMR.

Comment: @copper.hat It referred to non-aligned nations during the Cold War, fifty years ago. Nowadays, it means one of the Least-Developed Countries.

Comment: In PPP GDP per capita ranking, Iran is between Mexico and Argentina. Above China, Brazil or South Africa (and the world average for that matter). I think a better descriptor of them countries is 'developing economies' or some such. By analogy to individuals, one could think of a arbitrary line as 50% of world mean PPP GDP p.c as the line below which one ranks as poor. By that line, countries with  PPP GDP p.c < $8K would be 'third world'. This list includes 70 countries --India, Vietnam, Nigeria, Bangladesh, Pakistan (but not Morocco or Philippines)-- and over a third of world population.

Comment: @Mike interesting, I would have counted Iran as a Third World country without giving it a second thought, but of course I suffer from the bias of being educated in the 1970s, famously described by the late Hans Rosling in his [TED talk.](https://www.ted.com/talks/hans_rosling_shows_the_best_stats_you_ve_ever_seen) The IMF appears to list Iran as a "Developing Country" (Raider is now Twix) if we can believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developing_country#Developing_countries_according_to_International_Monetary_Fund)  ("it must be right, I have just written it yesterday!").

Comment: Just using Google, Iran is about six times better than the worst countries and about six times worse than the best. If Iran's mortality rate had been higher, then one could have compared the numbers with Libya, Lebanon, or Cuba to make them look bad. The "300 to 400 times higher percentage" is nonsense. The percentage is about 3 times higher than the US average. Which is by no means good or acceptable, but not the horror message as stated.

Answer (score 8):

It's plausible, but unclear. According to official statistics, Iranian women have a significantly lower maternal mortality rate than Ohio blacks. However, who has the higher infant mortality rate is harder to judge, because it has a less clear definition, the stats for the two populations are close, the rates are very similar and year-on-year changes potentially flip the result from one year to the next, and different sources disagree on what the rate is - for both Iran and Ohio - by enough to flip which of them has the higher rate.

The World Bank put the maternal mortality ratio for Iran in 2015 at 25 per 100000 live births. (Source: https://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=SH.STA.MMRT.) America's Health Rankings, on the other hand, puts the rate for blacks in Ohio at 46 per 100000 live births in 2018. (Source: https://www.americashealthrankings.org/explore/health-of-women-and-children/measure/maternal_mortality/state/OH.) Thus the comparison to Iran is probably true insofar as it applies to *maternal* mortality.

The claim about *infant* mortality, however is harder to be sure of. In part this is because of differences in reporting standards, explored (in the context of US healthcare) in Joseph Ahern's article [Do Differences in Reporting of Live Births Affect Comparability of Infant Mortality Rates?](https://www.communitysolutions.com/research/differences-reporting-live-births-affect-comparability-infant-mortality-rates/). (Spoiler: the answer is "yes".) Per official definition, any death of an infant who is born alive but then dies prior to their first birthday is supposed to count towards infant mortality statistics. In practice, however, the authors note that, for the purposes of statistical reporting, hospitals in some jurisdictions routinely consider premature babies born prior to a certain gestational age not to have been born alive - even if, in reality, they were - despite this practice having no justification in the definitions used by either the (international) WHO or the (American) CDC. For instance, they note that some hospitals in New York City do not count actually-alive births of babies of under 23 weeks' gestational age as live births. The article notes that the average "infant mortality rate" of hospitals in NYC that follow the official definitions strictly is 3.54 per 1000 live births, while those that apply a 23 week cutoff have a rate of 2.68 per 1000 live births. Though not explicitly stated, it seems to be implied that this one-third difference owes entirely to the difference in definitions.

This caveat is worth bearing in mind as we note that:

- https://childmortality.org/data puts the infant mortality rate for Iran at 14.9 per 1000 live births in 2017, while FRED [puts it at at 12.8 in 2017](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SPDYNIMRTINIRN)
- American's Health Rankings, citing CDC data, puts the rate for Ohio blacks at 12.9 in 2016 and 13.5 in 2018 (see: https://www.americashealthrankings.org/explore/health-of-women-and-children/measure/IMR_MCH/state/OH?edition-year=2018), while cleaveland.com, citing Ohio Deparment of Health, puts the rate at 13.8 in 2013 and 15.6 in 2017.

Depending upon which of these different stats we believe - if any of them - the infant mortality rate for African Americans in Ohio could be higher or lower than the overall rate in Iran. I don't know how to judge which of the stats are true, so I can't tell. Regardless of which is true, it's possible that the nominal "infant mortality rate" is really measuring a different thing in each country due to differences in reporting, potentially rendering the comparison between them meaningless.

Finally, note that America Health Rankings puts the overall infant mortality rate for Ohio at 7 per 1000 live births, suggesting that blacks have an infant mortality rate of only two times that of the general population. On maternal mortality, the stats are 20.3-per-100000 for the whole population vs 46-per-100000 for blacks. So Ryan's suggestion that blacks are 300-400 times more likely to suffer a death in childbirth - even if we charitably assume that he really meant 300%-400% more likely - seems not to be true. The real stat is more like "100% more likely".

Comment: It was stated that black persons are 50% of the population. That means you shouldn't compare "black" vs "average" but "black" vs. "not black". If there are 15.6 per 1,000 deaths for black people, and half the population is black, then for an average of 7.8 per 1,000 there would have to be no non-black child deaths at all, because the black deaths make that average already.

Comment: @gnasher729 Blacks are 14.2 of the Ohio population, not 50%. Given an overall rate of 7 and a black rate of 13.5 (not 15.6 - if we're going to directly compare rates, we should probably compare them from the same source wherever possible), that puts the non-black rate at (7 - 13.5 * 0.142) / 0.858 = 5.92 deaths per 1000. Which is still roughly a factor of 2, nowhere near the factor of 4-5 needed to justify "300%-400% more likely" or even the factor of 3 that would be needed to justify a claim of "300% *as* likely".